# Django two models in one view with ajax?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have created a view that give me the possibility to fill a form using an Ajax call. This the code:

```
# models.py

class CrudUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

# Views.py

from .models import CrudUser
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import JsonResponse

class CreateCrudUser(View):
    def  get(self, request):
        name1 = request.GET.get('name', None)
        address1 = request.GET.get('address', None)
        age1 = request.GET.get('age', None)

        obj = CrudUser.objects.create(
            name = name1,
            address = address1,
            age = age1
        )

        user = {'id':obj.id,'name':obj.name,'address':obj.address,'age':obj.age}

        data = {
            'user': user
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)'
```

But if I want to add a new models in my CreateCrudUser how could I do it?
Ad example the following one:

```
# models.py

    class Dog(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
        eyes_color= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        age= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you can send directly the object created, you don't need to pass the parameters again. And to get a new object you have to do the same as with the user:

```
class CreateCrudUser(View):
def  get(self, request):
    name1 = request.GET.get('name', None)
    address1 = request.GET.get('address', None)
    age1 = request.GET.get('age', None)


    dog_obj = Dog.objects.create(
        name = XXX,
        eyes_color = XXX,
        age = XXX
    )    

    obj = CrudUser.objects.create(
        name = name1,
        address = address1,
        age = age1
    )

    # you don't need this. user = {'id':obj.id,'name':obj.name,'address':obj.address,'age':obj.age}

    data = {
        'user': obj,
        'dog': dog_obj,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)'
```

By doing this you can access from your templates as:

```
{{ dog.name }} is the boss, and {{ user.name }} is not.
```

For example.

Comment: Woow great, thanks you for your answer. But just a question: If i want to display the db of each models in the same page, how could I get it?

Comment: when you say the db of each models you refer to the information of the objects in the database right? the `dog.name` or the `dog.eyes_color`. If that's the case and you are using django templates, is what I said at the end. use `{{ dog.name }}` and `{{ dog.eyes_color }}`. That will show you the `obj_dog` information because you are sending it as a `dog` variable inside the data to the template. Same with the `user` data .

Answer (score 0):

if the dog and user not connected (like the example above),i suggest to make ajax go to different URL for saving diffret types like go to `/User/add` for saving user and `Dog/add` for saving dog object ... if you want to make relation between them so you need to use [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) `FormSet` it's one of great things in Django that will look like Django admin inline like the pic :
[admin Inline formset related to main object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60SFI.png)